# Trying to deploy tomcat server through Intellij IDEA and getting a weird missing server.xml error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, maven, intellij-idea

I'll start with the error I'm receiving, and then explain what I have done so far.

```
Error running Guestbook: Cannot load /home/anthony/.IntelliJIdea11/system/tomcat/Unnamed_guestbook-spring/conf/server.xml
```

Using Intellij IDEA 11 Ultimate Edition:

I've added the tomcat6 server in the settings -> application servers menu of Intellij IDEA by adding the directory where tomcat is installed, then I went to edit configurations in the run drop-down box, and added the tomcat server local defaults.  Under the deployment tab, I clicked + -> Artifacts... and selected the ProjectName:war file artifact.

Now, when I ran it the first time, it gave me some error like

```
no conf folder found in /home/anthony/.IntelliJIdea11/system/tomcat/Unnamed_guestbook-spring/
```

In a moment of desperation I just made a directory called conf there and the error message, sure enough, changed to:

```
Cannot load /home/anthony/.IntelliJIdea11/system/tomcat/Unnamed_guestbook-spring/conf/server.xml
```

I have no idea where this file should be found, what should be in it, why it's not being created, or most of all - how to get it in the right place.  Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: IDEA should take your `TOMCAT/conf/server.xml`, modify it and copy into the temp location. For some reason it doesn't happen. Try the new vanilla Tomcat 6 installation from Apache site, make sure the original file exists.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I have to say, I've seen lots of people waste lots of time over the years trying to control web servers with IDE plug-ins. Bottom line - it's just not worth it. Tomcat is so simple to run from the command-line, that I've never seen the benefit of doing from the IDE. If you are looking for auto-deployment, just create a Tomcat context file, and point it at your development environment - no 'deployment' necessary.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek then you miss the benefits of hot deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to CrazyCoder for the tip - I downloaded a vanilla Tomcat 7 installation and added that one in the Application Servers menu, then changed the run configuration to use this instead, and it started right up.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: can you tell me where I can download vanilla tomacat 7 from. I could not find it.

Comment: I am using a fresh download of Tomcat 8.5.16. I too get the same kind of error with `Unamed_` prefixing the name of my app.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me too. I found out that I accidentally edited server.xml file and it was no longer a valid xml. As it couldn't be parsed properly, it wasn't loaded in. Fixing server.xml resolved the issue.