# adding spring file to idea (13) tomcat 6 or 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a working project in eclipse which i like to also run in idea ( my preferred IDE environment ). i am using tomcat 6 and it seem for some reason that i cannot get the spring file to be loaded. including *.xml file  etc, they are all OK on eclipse but dont work on Idea.

i saw this post [Trying to deploy tomcat server through Intellij IDEA and getting a weird missing server.xml error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881639/trying-to-deploy-tomcat-server-through-intellij-idea-and-getting-a-weird-missing)

but switching to tomcat 7 didn't helped me.

Comment: Server.xml is from tomcat and not a spring file, right? What spring file are you talking about?

Comment: I have lots of json xml and other .xml files under web-inf that do not seem to be taken with tomcat. the tomcat starts but it doesnt know my spring controllers